# Button should be visible when the user is done selecting the value through slider

Tags: iphone, uislider

I need to implement such kind of functionality in my slider such that the submit button should not appear till the user pull up his fingers from slider.
Is there any kind of function which can duplicate this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't set `continuous` to `NO` for some reason, observe the `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` events:

```
[yourSlider addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(showSubmit:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

And

```
- (void)showSubmit:(UISlider *) {
    // code to show your button here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The UISlider has a `continuous` property. Set this to NO, and you will only receive valueChanged events when the user is done choosing his value. Then add a target for the valueChanged event, and there you can set the button to be enabled.